# How to make all matplotlib histogram rectangles in one color and set words written on x-axis on vertical position?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: I need to get such result]
[image: I have this now]

How can I make all histogram rectangles in one color, make certain grid as on photo, and set words written on x-axis on vertical position as on example?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,7))  
ax = fig.add_subplot()  
plt.title('Survived vs Sex')  
ax.bar('Female', survivedf/totalf)  
ax.bar('Male', survivedm/totalm)  
ax.set_xlabel('Sex')  
plt.legend('Survived')  
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.bar(..., color='royalblue')` to have blue bars. `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)` to rotate the tick labels.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `bar` function just once and pass a list/an array with all the values you want to plot. You don't have to call it for every single value you want to plot. Tick labels can be rotated with the `rotation`-argument of the `plt.xticks` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(['female', 'male'], [0.7, 0.2])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Or alternatively, use the object oriented interface:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1) 

labels = ['female', 'male']
ax.bar(labels, [0.7, 0.2])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
```